# A question about independence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence, bernoulli-distribution

Let $C \sim \hbox{Bernoulli}(p)$. Given $X$ and $Y$ two independent random variables. Consider the following experiment to define a new random variable $Z$:
$$
Z=\begin{cases}
X & \text{if } C=0 \\
Y & \text{if } C=1
\end{cases}
$$

It's intuitive to me to say that $Z$ is a random variable **dependent** on $C$. But, in my intuition, $C$ is **independent** of $Z$. So my question is:

How to show this?
$$E[C|Z]=E[C]$$

Comment: Why would you think that $C$ was independent of $Z$?  Say $X$ has very large positive support and $Y$ has large negative support.  Then knowing that $Z$ was a big positive number tells us what $C$ must have been.

Comment: Maybe the author meant to say that X and Y are iid?

Comment: No. $X$ and $Y$ are just independent. But in my head, let's say $C$ happens first and then I choose who's going to be $Z$. This makes me think that $C$ is independent of $Z$ (or of $X$ and $Y$). See, can I state that $P(C|Z)=P(C)$? If so, then this gives me the idea that $C$ is independent in some sense of $Z$, although the converse is not true.

Comment: @AndréGoulart See my answer below.  The statement "$C$ is independent of $Z$" means that knowing $Z$ tells you nothing about $C$, not that $Z$ causes $C$ to take a certain value.  It is not true that $P(C|Z)=P(C)$ because knowing the value of $Z$ can tell you the value of $C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution and both are independent of $C$, then $Z$ would also be independent of $C$ because knowing $C$ tells you nothing about the values of $Z$.

If $X$ and $Y$ don't have the same distribution, then, as pointed out in the comments, $Z$ and $C$ would not be independent.  As an extreme example, suppose that $X$ is always an even number and $Y$ is always an odd number.  Then $Z$ is not independent of $C$ because if you knew that $C=1$, you would also know that $Z$ is odd.  Similarly, $C$ is not independent of $Z$ because if you knew $Z$ is even, then you would also know that $C=0$.

I think the confusion comes from the mathematical meaning of "independence" vs a more colloquial meaning.  In math, "independence" of two random variables means that knowing information about one tells you nothing about the other.  It's a symmetric relationship: If $X$ is independent of $Y$, then $Y$ is independent of $X$.  It says nothing about causation.  Colloquially, though, if one says that an event $A$ is independent of another event $B$, they might mean that $B$ doesn't cause $A$, or that $A$ doesn't cause $B$, or something else along these lines.  This ambiguity is why mathematical definitions are formalized to precise statements.

Comment: Yes, I think that was my confusion. I thought that $C$ was independent of $Z$ for the simple reason that it happened before I chose $Z$ and in that sense, in my mind, I thought that $C$ did not depend on $Z$. Good to know that I was wrong to claim that $E[C|Z]=E[C]$.

Comment: @AndréGoulart a better way of thinking about dependence and independence could be asking whether knowing the value $Z$ gives you additional information about $C$.

Answer (score 0):

$$Z=(1-C)X+CY\, \Rightarrow E(E(C|Z)e^{it Z})=E(Ce^{it Z})=pE(e^{itY})$$ Doing $t=0$ you get $E(C|Z)=E(C).$ (However $C$ and $Z$ are not independent)